# En electron.js, ¿cómo cambio de html a otro html sin que se recargue la app)

Tags: javascript, html, electron

Pues en resumen es eso, estoy trabajando una app en electron.js, para ello tengo distintos html que son las distintas pantallas de la app, mi problema es que al cambiar de, por ejemplo, la pagina de inicio a otra, se recarga la pagina, es decir, se ve en blanco por unos pocos milisegundos, lo cual no da la sensación de ser una app de escritorio, que es a lo que quiero llegar.

¿Cómo puedo realizar transiciones entre distintos html y que no se recargue?, o se vea ese intervalo con la pantalla en blanco.

Comment: Deberías crear una SPA (aplicación de una única página) y con Javascript modificar lo que se ve trabajando con el DOM.

Answer (score 0):

nose si esto te puede servir y si es lo que buscas pero creo que si, https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/javascript/#tabs , de todas formas en bootstrap tienes muchos más ejemeplos y cositas parecidas :)